# How to read file using Apache Camel, process the file using Spring batch, read each line and route it back through Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-batch, reroute

Would like to know how to pass the JAXBElement to a Camel route, which processed from each line of the batch file read through Spring batch loaded through Camel Route.

Code snippets given below uses a customerWriter method to call JMSTemplate to write the message to a Queue. Instead I need to route the message to another Camel route.

**Current:** CamelRoute -> ReadFile -> Spring Batch -> Process Each line -> Queue

**Expected:** CamelRoute -> ReadFile -> Spring Batch -> Process Each line -> Camel Route

**Camel Route to read the file:**

```
@Override
public void configure()  {

    String fromUri = batchLoadPath + "?" + batchFileOptions;
    from(fromUri).process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange msg)  {
            File file = msg.getIn().getBody(File.class);
            String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();

            try {
                JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("input.file.name", fileName).addDate("dateTime", new Date()).toJobParameters();
                jobLauncher.run(importCustomerJob, jobParameters);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(Process file encountered error:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

    })
    .to("log:EndBatch");
```

**Batch Config:**

```
@Bean
public JmsItemWriter<String> customerWriter() {
    JmsItemWriter<String> writer = new JmsItemWriter<String>();
    writer.setJmsTemplate(jmsTemplate);
    return writer;
}

public Job importCustomerJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step step1) {
    JobBuilder builder = jobBuilderFactory.get("importCustomerJob");
    builder.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer());
    builder.listener(listener);
    JobFlowBuilder jfb = builder.flow(step1);
    jfb.end();
    Job job = jfb.build().build();
    return job;
}

@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    // Read chunk of 10 records and writing those as messages to queue
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Customer, String>chunk(10)
            .reader(customerReader())
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipPolicy(fileVerificationSkipper())
            .processor(customerItemProcessor())
            .writer(customerWriter())
            .listener(customerReader())
            .build();
}
```

**Batch Processor:**

```
public class CustomerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Customer, String> {
    @Autowired
    JaxbUtil jaxbUtil;

    public String process(Customer item) throws Exception {
        // Mapping code goes here
        JAXBElement<CustomerX> mobj = customerFactory.createCustomerX(cp);
        return jaxbUtil.objectToXml(mobj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from a Camel point of view, to call another Camel route you simply add a `.to()` statement. For example to call an in-memory route synchronously, you can use `direct:`.

```
from(fromUri).process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange msg)  {
        ... your processor impl
    }
})
.to("direct:yourOtherRoute")
.to("log:EndBatch"); 

from("direct:yourOtherRoute")
...
```

To pass the result of the processor to the next route, the processor must set this result into the Exchange Body.

Comment: What I am trying is to send the processed line from spring batch to camel route, not camel route to another camel route.

Comment: If you want to call the Camel route from your Java code, you have to use Remoting/Proxy such as [Spring Remoting](http://camel.apache.org/spring-remoting.html), [Camel-Proxy](http://camel.apache.org/using-camelproxy.html) or set up a Camel route with a reachable endpoint (HTTP or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for the response @burki. Let me try that solution. Meanwhile would be great if you can please share any example code

Comment: @Vijai You can use a [`ProducerTemplate`](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) to send arbitrary data from within Java code to a camel route as well

Comment: @RomanVottner Thanks! Figured out a solution by replacing JMSItemWriter with CamelItemWriter and using ProducerTemplate. Will provide the code for reference later today.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions @Burki and @Roman Vottner. Here's the code which I modified and it worked.

**Solution:**

Added a writer method in **Batch Config**  and called it instead of JMSWriter

```
@Bean
public CamelItemWriter<String> customerCamelWriter() {
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
    CamelItemWriter<String> writer = new CamelItemWriter<String>(producerTemplate, "direct:process");
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    // Read chunk of 10 records and writing those as messages to CAS.TRF.MDM queue
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Customer, String>chunk(10)
            .reader(customerReader())
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipPolicy(fileVerificationSkipper())
            .processor(customerItemProcessor())
            .writer(customerCamelWriter())
            .listener(customerReader())
            .build();
}
```